# Access all instances of class with foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, composite

I can't get the "foreach" function to work properly. When I select a node in the treeView it should display the sum of the times for each children/grandchildrens (every node contains an integer time variable) pretty much like the usual examples with hierarchy tree over a company and when a boss is selected it should sum up the subordinates salaries. But for some reason it only sum up the childrens times, it only goes one step down in the list of subordinates so to speak.

Hope what I'm trying to achieve is clear, if not please tell me and I'll try to explain it further!

```
// This is in the Form1 class and is calles when a node is selected in a treeView:
private void getTimeSum(ProductionElement prod)
{

    int sum;

    sum = prod.getSumOfTimes();
    totalTimeLabel.Text = sum.ToString();
}

class CompositeElement : ProductionElement
{
    //The composite class for the composite pattern

    protected List<ProductionElement> subordinates = new List<ProductionElement>();

    public int getSumOfTimes()
    {
         int sum;

         foreach (var prodel in subordinates)
         {
              sum += prodel.getIdealTime();
         }

         return sum;
    }

    public int getIdealTime()
    {
        return idealTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `foreach` works just fine - you simply don't understand the composite pattern.

Comment: @JohnSaunders yes you're probably right! The thing that confuses me about the pattern in my example is that sometimes the user should set a time for a composite and sometimes the time for that composite (and the parent for that and so forth) should be calculated using leafs. More precisely, an activity (a composite) is based on subactivities (composites) that are based on elements (leafs). But if one doesn't want to get the time for the subactivity from building it up with elements, one can set the time for that subactivity and still get the time for the activity correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use recursion -- typically you would only have values at a leaf node in such a case... like this:

```
public int getSumOfTimes()
{
     int sum;

     if (subordinates.Count() == 0)
     {
       sum =  getIdealTime();
     }
     else
     {
       foreach (var prodel in subordinates)
       {
         sum += prodel.getSumOfTimes();
       }
     }
     return sum;
}
```

If you have data at a regular node also then you would need to add a call to getIdealTime() after the foreach

Comment: Yes, I've got the composite pattern all wrong as I said in the answer above. But I can't get any of your code to work, which is strange! Can't one have data in both the composites as well as the leafs and sum all the data of that kind no matter if it's in a leaf or composite?

Answer (score 1):

If your production element defines a `getIdealTime`, then your composite element should define a `getIdealTime` that takes all its children into account. So you would want to put the code for `getSumOfTimes` into the `getIdealTime` function instead. That way, other composite elements within your list would automatically go through their own list to calculate their value.

If you don’t want that—although that would be the point about the composite pattern—then you could still fix your implementation to check for other composite elements explicitely:

```
foreach (var prodel in subordinates)
{
    if (prodel is CompositeElement)
        sum += ((CompositeElement)prodel).getSumOfTimes();
    else
        sum += prodel.getIdealTime();
}
```

Comment: Yes you're right, it seems like I've got the composite pattern a bit wrong. The thing is that the user could choose if he'd like to set the time for a node or calculate it with the leafs idealTime (but the leaf are not just the same as the composite so I cant just use composites). I can't get it to work though, I tried your code as well as Hogans but now it says "0" no mater what I select.

Answer (score 0):

To get the sum do something like:

```
public int getSumOfTimes(List<ProductionElement> subordinates)
{
     return subordinates.Sum(prodel => prodel.idealTime);
}
```